# Tuple Traits Explanation

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
 
namespace a::b::c
{
    inline constexpr std::string_view str{ "hello" };
}
 
template <class... T>
std::tuple<std::size_t, std::common_type_t<T...>> sum(T... args)
{
    return { sizeof...(T), (args + ...) };
}
 
int main()
{
    auto [iNumbers, iSum]{ sum(1, 2, 3) };
    std::cout << a::b::c::str << ' ' << iNumbers << ' ' << iSum << '\n';
 
    std::array arr{ 1, 2, 3 };
 
    std::cout << std::size(arr) << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I'm getting this error.

> 1>D:\Programming\CPP\LearningCPP\LearningCPP.cpp(28,9): error C2440:
> 'return': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to
> 'std::tuple<size_t,std::common_type<int,int,int>>'
> 1>D:\Programming\CPP\LearningCPP\LearningCPP.cpp(27,1): message : No
> constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
> resolution was ambiguous
> 1>D:\Programming\CPP\LearningCPP\LearningCPP.cpp(33): message : see
> reference to function template instantiation
> 'std::tuple<size_t,std::common_type<int,int,int>>
> sum<int,int,int>(int,int,int)' being compiled

This is source code which is used in Learncpp.com . Actually I was having difficult understanding and I'm getting these errors, I have changed the compiler version to c++17 still getting these errors and the code can someone help me by explain the code thanks

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/TPhcYaobY)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fae2462744ef1ca)

Comment: What compiler, version, and compiler settings are you using to compile the code with?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2019 with cpp language standard as 
ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)